# I am trying to use checkbox to change color of element but it doesn't works

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to use "check box" to change color of element.

**HTML**:

```
<label for="toggle-1">I'm a toggle</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div class="reklama">I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.reklama {
  color:Red;
}

input#toggle-1: checked ~ .reklama{
  color:green;  
}
```

U can find my demo **[here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/uAFY6/)**.

Comment: remove the space before the `:checked`

Comment: Please add a code block inline. Also, please give a description of what exactly does not work, what you tried to make it work, what you expected from it and what you got. Failing to do this will invariably get your question downvoted, so just a heads up.

Comment: @King King thank u, i forgot that xD.

Comment: @Sharadh sry about that, i posted link to my fiddle, next time i will pute code block.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have any spaces before the ":checked", so that it is directly connected to your id. This will work in your CSS

```
input#toggle-1:checked ~ .reklama{
```